# Write the sum $\sum\limits_{a \in \mathbb{N}}\sum\limits_{b \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(a,b)}{a^sb^t}$ in terms of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I have the following exercise, and I need some help:

Write the sum
$$\sum\limits_{a \in \mathbb{N}}\sum\limits_{b \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(a,b)}{a^sb^t}$$ in terms of the Riemann zeta function ($(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor).
I assume you have to somehow sort the sums for $d:=(a,b)$, but I have no idea how, any help is appreciated.

I tried to use the fact that $d=xa + yb$ and then
$$ \frac{(a,b)}{a^sb^t} = \frac{x}{a^{s-1}b^t} + \frac{y}{a^sb^{t-1}}$$
but since I don't know if the original series is convergent or not, I can't use re-arrangements and so I got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to math exchange! is this from a book or ?

Comment: Not sure, it is a homework problem

Comment: oh okay thanks for pointing it out'

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being clearer. It's a homework that I don't a grade for, more like a 'Convice yourself that it is true' type of exercise.  I was trying to play around with the fact that d can be written as x*a + y*b and then somehow rearrange the sums but, then I realised that I can't take the rearrangement for granted, since I don't know if the sum is absolutely convergent. And I don't see another approach to the problem

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the quick answer! I upvoted it, but since this is my first time on the page I don't have 15 reputations yet, so it doesn't show, but will do it again, when I can!:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, define

$$f(s,t;u)=\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b= 1}^\infty\frac{(a,b)^u}{a^sb^t}$$

We seek to derive a formula for $f(s,t;1)$, though this process will naturally lead us toward a more general formula for $f(s,t;u)$. We may perform the following manipulations:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(s,t;u)&=\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{(a,b)^u}{a^sb^t}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{(a,b)=r}\frac{r^u}{a^sb^t}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{r^u}{(ar)^s(br)^t}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r^{s+t-u}}\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{1}{{a}^s{b}^t}\\
&=\zeta(s+t-u)\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{1}{a^sb^t}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now, simply note that $f(s,t;0)=\zeta(s)\zeta(t)$, so setting $u=0$ and rearanging the above equation, we have that

$$\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{1}{a^sb^t}
=\frac{f(s,t;0)}{\zeta(s+t)}=\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(t)}{\zeta(s+t)}$$

and therefore,

$$\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b= 1}^\infty\frac{(a,b)^u}{a^sb^t}=
f(s,t;u)=\zeta(s+t-u)\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{1}{a^sb^t}=\frac{\zeta(s+t-u)\zeta(s)\zeta(t)}{\zeta(s+t)}$$

Finally, setting $u=1$, we have your particular case:

$$\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b= 1}^\infty\frac{(a,b)}{a^sb^t}=\frac{\zeta(s+t-1)\zeta(s)\zeta(t)}{\zeta(s+t)}$$

Comment: You didn't say anything about the expression for $\sum_{(a,b)=1} a^{-s} b^{-t}$

Comment: @reuns Reread the proof. I evaluate this sum in the second to last math line, right after "$f(s,t;0)=\zeta(s)\zeta(t)$". I'm using the expression for $f(s,t;0)$ to derive an expression for $\sum_{(a,b)=1}a^{-s}b^{-t}$, not the other way around. $\tag*{}$Should I swap the order of the equalities (or do something else) to make this more clear?

Comment: @reuns I have modified the order of that equality (and made a few minor edits) to hopefully make my solution a bit more clear. Are things more clear now?

Comment: This is really nice!

Comment: One interesting special case is $\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a^2b^2}=\frac{5}{2}\zeta(3)$.

Answer (score 4):

Using the convolution property of Euler's totient function, we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{a\ge1}\sum_{b\ge1}{(a,b)\over a^sb^t}
&=\sum_{a\ge1}\sum_{b\ge1}{1\over a^sb^t}\sum_{d|(a,b)}\varphi(d)=\sum_{d\ge1}\varphi(d)\sum_{\substack{a\ge1\\d|a}}{1\over a^s}\sum_{\substack{b\ge1\\d|b}}{1\over b^t} \\
&=\sum_{d\ge1}{\varphi(d)\over d^{s+t}}\sum_{\substack{a\ge1\\d|a}}{1\over(a/d)^s}\sum_{\substack{b\ge1\\d|b}}{1\over(b/d)^t}=\sum_{d\ge1}{\varphi(d)\over d^{s+t}}\sum_{u\ge1}{1\over u^s}\sum_{v\ge1}{1\over v^t} \\
&={\zeta(s+t-1)\over\zeta(s+t)}\cdot\zeta(s)\zeta(t).
\end{aligned}

Comment: @C-RAM Edited. Thanks for pointing that out!